# Why subprocess did not execute some commands of adb?

Tags: python, android, adb

Here I would like to execute the adb command from python script but **adb devices** command does not give any output (I want to get adb devices command output), but if I run command separately in cmd it's worked. And also I connect my device through the usb to pc. So what is the problem here.

Here is my python script

```
import os
import subprocess 


file_ = open('shell_output.txt', 'w') 
subprocess.run('adb tcpip 5555', shell=True, stdout=file_) 
subprocess.run('adb devices', shell=True, stdout=file_) 
file_.close()
```

Here in shell_output.txt file adb devices command it did not show the attached list of devices but separately it's worked.

Comment: Just a guess: Some error occurs but the error message is sent to stderr and therefore not captured in "file_".

Comment: @MichaelButscher Yes, I agree. Adding `stderr=file_` as an argument to the run method would likely fix this issue.

Comment: There are several Python packages that provide adb commands, may be one of those works better especially in case of errors: https://pypi.org/search/?q=adb

Comment: It's also possible `adb devices` returns an empty list because it's called too fast after the `adb tcpip` call. A quick-n-dirty fix would be to add a `time.sleep()` call. A nicer fix would be to loop on the call until it returns something.